# Trying to Mimic depth and Orientation in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am attempting to plot a data series on xyz axis. I have successfully splotted the data series I want, but cannot get a pleasing orientation and depth to view the graph. When I try to orient the Z axis like that of the example graph, it changes positioning (I am using windows mode on gnuplot). In the process I tend to lose view of my axes and some curves in the data series get eclipsed by others. Any recommendations on how I can improve my graph in progress would be greatly appreciated, thank you [Graph in progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI7OW.png) [Example Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYR3S.png)

p.s. Do not mind the legend, I plan on getting rid of it.

| X1 | Y1 | Z1 | X2 | Y2 | Z2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 75 | 1 |
| 500 | 24 | 0 | 500 | 14 | 14 |

```html
X1 | Y1 | Z1| X2| Y2 | Z2
| --- | --- | ---|---| ---| --|
| 0 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 75 | 1|
| 500| 24| 0| 500| 14| 14| 1
```

0   78.641  0   0   74.725  1   0   72.148  2   0   75.504  3   0   72.244  5   0   72.839  12
1   78.094  0   1   74.499  1   1   72.793  2   1   76.035  3   1   72.25   5   1   72.81   12
2   77.924  0   2   74.969  1   2   72.569  2   2   75.912  3   2   72.311  5   2   72.666  12
3   78.142  0   3   75.283  1   3   71.873  2   3   75.537  3   3   72.649  5   3   73.274  12
4   77.854  0   4   75.441  1   4   72.214  2   4   75.68   3   4   72.393  5   4   73.344  12

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm trying to get my 'graph in progress' to look like the 'example graph'.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your code? How does your data look like? Could you please create and add a minimal example? Have you checked the examples on the gnuplot homepage? e.g. http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.4/fenceplot.html

Comment: Hi, I do not have the reputation to post pictures yet, but I have linked two pictures at the end of my post. One is the graph I currently have, and the other graph is the example I'm trying to mimic. As for the code, i've been organically adding different settings, so I'm not sure how to get the code for the graph I linked. Very new to gnuplot.

In general, I'm using default splot with STDOUT '0 color solid butt enhanced standalone wsize 2880,1476'. xyplane set to 3. If there's a way to output code displaying a graph, please let me know!

Comment: Thanks. Please add example data as text (format as code) not as image.

Comment: Give me one second to figure that out haha.

Comment: Simply paste as text what you posted as image before. Don't try to make a fancy table...

Comment: I did not see that comment as I was making a very fancy table. I went ahead and pasted the first four rows of my data from my csv at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to plot your data in such a way (waterfall/fence), you need to have some "suitable" data for this.
Otherwise some other representation might be better.
Take the following example as starting point. Although, I am not yet fully convinced about the result and perhaps you might experience some surprises with the representation of the plot when you rotate it.
The code certainly needs to be adapted to your detailed requirements which are misssing.

**Code:**

```
### "waterfall/fence" plot 
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0   78.641   0   0   74.725   1   0   72.148   2   0   75.504   3   0   72.244   5   0   72.839   12
1   78.094   0   1   74.499   1   1   72.793   2   1   76.035   3   1   72.25    5   1   72.81    12
2   77.924   0   2   74.969   1   2   72.569   2   2   75.912   3   2   72.311   5   2   72.666   12
3   78.142   0   3   75.283   1   3   71.873   2   3   75.537   3   3   72.649   5   3   73.274   12
4   77.854   0   4   75.441   1   4   72.214   2   4   75.68    3   4   72.393   5   4   73.344   12
EOD

set style fill transparent solid 0.5
set xyplane at 70
set key noautotitle
set view 66,106
set grid x,y
set xtic 1
set ytics offset 0,-0.5
set zrange [70:80]

splot for [i=1:6] $Data u i*3-2:i*3:i*3-1 w lp pt 7 lc i, \
      for [i=1:6] $Data u i*3-2:i*3:i*3-1:(70):i*3-1 w zerrorfill lc i ti sprintf("%d",i)
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: @cjbrazel Problem solved, question answered? Thank you on SO = accept/upvote.

Comment: I can't vote due to current reputation, but did not notice the checkmark. Checked!

Comment: @cjbrazel now you can ;-)